# unable to copy file from s3 to ubuntu local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, wget

I have installed aws client and configured with an access key, secret key, and region.
When I am running aws s3 cp command from the command line it is working and returning the image.

```
ws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/FOLDERNAME/abc.jpg /var/images/
```

but when I am using the same above command under shell script it is not copying the image to designation.

Here is a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
searchstring="/cases/"
foldername="/"
while read line
do
        data=$line
        name=${data#*$searchstring}
        replaced=$(echo $name | sed -e 's/\//_/g')
        folder=${name%$foldername*}
        path=/root/scripts/odometer/

        aws s3 cp s3://*****-production-/cases/$name $path --recursive  --region us-east-1
done < export.txt
```

I tried with all other option as well by removing recursive, and region, keeping one removing other but didn't get success.

I also tried using `wget` command by giving the full path of s3 image but still unable to download.

```
root@oltau-training:~/scripts# wget https://****production-***.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cases/132/1525770896114.jpg -P /root/scripts/odometer/
--2019-09-28 05:43:40--  https://****production-***.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cases/132/1525770896114.jpg
Resolving ****production-***.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com (****production-***.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com... 5*.219.*8.48
Connecting to ****production-***.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com (****production-***.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com)|5*.219.*8.48|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2019-09-28 05:43:40 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I intend to copy images from s3 to local machine either using aws s3 command or wget command. 
Note- I have full access to my s3 account

Answer (score 1):

You can not wget image if the object is private, for public image you can try something like `wget --no-check-certificate --no-proxy 'http://your_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my-file.jpg'`.

if this `aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/FOLDERNAME/abc.jpg /var/images/` work, it means the problem with bash script variables expansion.

So better to echo the command before trying to get the object from s3 and verify is all variable properly set.

```
echo "aws s3 cp s3://*****-production-/cases/$name $path --recursive  --region us-east-1"
```

Another thing that may cause to this issue can be, double-check the region  `--region us-east-1`. as in the first command, it will pick the default region.

Also if you are copying single file then remove `--recursive`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while copying to or from s3 bucket from my bash script. All I did was check the path where my aws cli is installed and add that path in your script. You can check your aws cli path with bash command **which aws**

Your command in the shell script will be:
**/path/aws s3 cp....**